# How do I create a weekly recurring notification in Flutter?(Solved)

Tags: flutter, notifications, local, schedule

How can I create recurring notification in Flutter?

How can I create recurring notification using flutter_local_notifications package?
You can fix the problem using this code. Change the variables that don't work because they're part of my own code.

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
void main() async {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
runApp())
}
```

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
```

```
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin localNotificationPlg;
  var array = model.days!;
  if (model.enabled!) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    late DateTime nextGivenDay;

    var days = AppTranslations.getDays();
    print(array);
    for (var item in array) {
      print(item);
      var day = days.firstWhere((x) => x.dayCode == item);
      var id =
          int.parse(model.id.toString() + day.dayNo.toString());
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        DateTime nextDate = now.add(Duration(days: i));
        int dayOfWeek = nextDate.weekday;
        if (dayOfWeek == (day.dayNo+1)) {
          nextGivenDay = nextDate;
          nextGivenDay = DateTime(nextGivenDay.year,nextGivenDay.month,nextGivenDay.day,hour,minute);
          if (nextGivenDay.isBefore(now)) {
            nextGivenDay = nextGivenDay.add(Duration(days: 7));
          }
          print(nextGivenDay.toString());
          break;
        }
      }
      await localNotificationPlg.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        'Reminder',
        'Water Reminder',
        tz.TZDateTime.from(nextGivenDay, tz.local),
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime,
      );
    }`
```

Comment: There is this article about using local notifications in Flutter -> https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/local-notifications-in-flutter/. It might help you out. Full disclosure, I wrote this article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I couldn't find any resources on this and I asked and answered the question myself.